# Передача массива в качестве параметра при использовании рефлексии

Tags: c#

Допустим есть класс с двумя методами

```
class myClass
{
    public string Method1 ()
    {}
    public string Method2 (string param1, string [,] code_array)
    {}
}
```

Необходимо вызывать данные методы используя рефлексию, делаю так

```
Type thisType = this.GetType();
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("Method1");
theMethod.Invoke(this, userParameters);
```

Но непонятно как можно передать параметры для второго метода - строку и массив строк.

Comment: Если вы хотите таким образом обходить `switch`, я бы посоветовал вам измерить скорость со `switch` и с рефлексией, сравнить и удивиться.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, но рефлексия удобнее на первый взгляд в применении. Можно оперировать на другом классе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Type thisType = this.GetType();
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("Method2", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string[,]) });
var stringParam = "someString";
var arrayParam = new string [2,2];
theMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { stringParam, arrayParam });
```

Comment: я бы еще добавил такое: `MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod("Method1", new Type[] {typeof(нужный тип),....});`

Comment: а для чего этот typeof ? возвращаемое значение метода ?

Comment: @e1s фильтр методов по принимаемым параметрам

Comment: @e1s для того чтоб не делать так: `theMethod.Invoke(this, new object[] { stringParam, stringParam });` а делать так: `theMethod.Invoke(this, new[] { stringParam, stringParam });`

Comment: @Dmitry спасибо, добавил.  new [] и без фильтра в GetMethod будет работать, просто старая привычка прописывать явно тип массива осталась. C# выражение `new [] { stringParam, arrayParam }` не может нормально проглотить - но у топикастера готовый массив сверху приходит, так что без разницы.

Comment: @PashaPash Впринципе да, не обязательно сокращать до new[], но вот указывать типы при известной сигнатуре желательно всегда, ибо могут возникнуть траблы с перегруженными методами.